# How to play a video after pausing (for a few seconds) in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

What I have is a video (introVid) and what I'd like to happen is when it reaches the 1 second mark, it needs to pause for 2 seconds and then play again. Here is the code but it won't play after 2 seconds. It just keeps the paused state.

```
introVid.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){

    if(this.currentTime > 1) {
        this.pause();
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.play();    
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: can you not simply turn the listener off after it's triggered, so when you play again it doesn't trigger? or you could set a flag or point to a new function if you still need the timeupdate listener active

Answer (score 0):

Add `this.load();` above `this.play();` to start the video over from the beginning.

Right now, your listener is triggered immediately when the video resumes (thus pausing the video again), because the video's position is not reset.

Updated JS:

```
introVid.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
    if(this.currentTime > 1) {
        this.pause();
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.load();    
            this.play();    
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: What if I want to start from where I left off? Like continue from 1 onwards?

Comment: @catandmouse Do you mean you want to play through the video in 1-second intervals with 2-second pauses between each second?

Comment: The video I have is just 2 seconds long. I just want the screen at 1-sec mark to linger for a while (2 seconds) before continuing. So that it feels the video is 4 seconds rather than just 2 seconds.